# python if variable == string wont work when you enter correct value

Tags: python

Hi i am am trying to make a program where if you enter hi it will say you rule but if you enter anything else it will say sucker
my current code is

```
import sys
print("enter your password")
pword = (sys.stdin.readline())
if pword == "hi"
print("i rule")
else:
print("sucker")
```

please help!

Comment: At first, I think you need to write python codes that the python interpreter understands; say, correct indentation

Comment: And add a colon on the `if` line.

Comment: please first try to run your code before posting. also you should strip off newline char from input stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add strip to remove unwanted space/newline characters

```
import sys
print("enter your password")
pword = (sys.stdin.readline())
if pword.strip() == "hi":
    print("i rule")
else:
    print("sucker")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
pword = input()
```

Or if it's Python 2.x, use `raw_input()` instead.

But fix your indentation first, and add a colon after `if pword == "hi"`.

Answer (score 0):

no need to import sys(except you want to)

```
pword = input("enter your password")
if pword == "hi":
    print("i rule")
else:
    print("sucker")
```

If you want to the correct code is:(you forgotten an : in the if statment)

```
import sys
print("enter your password")
pword = (sys.stdin.readline())
if pword.strip() == "hi":
print("i rule")
else:
print("sucker")
```